# Tax price issue on the product and listing page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-calculation

I am facing an issue with the price display on the listing page and product page.

There are three cases:

> Case 1: Display Product Prices In Catalog -> Including Tax

The price display on the front-end is 34,56 €
[image]

> Case 2: Display Product Prices In Catalog -> Excluding Tax

The price display on the front-end is 29,04 €
[image]

> Case 3: Display Product Prices In Catalog -> Including and Excluding
>   Tax

The price display on the front-end is 33,99 € 28,56 €
[image]

I want to display 33.99€ with the including tax. I don't know why there is displaying 34.56 instead of 33.99. 
The same configuration working for Magento 1 website. In the Magento 1 site, there is showing 33.99 € on the front-end.Can you guys help me? Your help would be appreciated.

Please see my configuration in below screenshots,

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your magento version M2.x.x.?

Comment: Magento version is 2.3.0

Comment: What is your actual price?

Answer (score 2):

I think the first price of 34.56€ comes from the fact that you are displaying the shipping price.

If you check your screenshots, you set `Display shipping price: including tax`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, it is adding extra shipping price.

Comment: All configurations are correct as in my Magento 1 store.There is an issue regarding the Price display only. The price is correct if i set catalogue price value with 'including' or 'excluding or including'. The price must be shown 33.99 instead of 34.56.If i add product then price display 33.99 which is correct.Please see this screenshot. https://nimb.ws/7qMfgC

Comment: Did you change the field "Display shipping price" to see what happens?
Also, are your price set excluding tax or including tax? could you make a screenshot about the "Calculation Settings" section?

Comment: tax setting- https://nimb.ws/6CNmSu        shipping setting - https://nimb.ws/QsaqeA     same configuration working in Magento 1, you caan see 33.99 on the product page -- https://nimb.ws/1MtvlV

Comment: It's the same behaviour for all products or only this one? I assume that you already run the reindex command line right? Can you create a simple product with a price at 100€ from the back office? I would like to see what happened to the price

Comment: Once again, when I see your 3 screenshots, at first glance the first price includes the shipping price. https://ibb.co/ZcYF49B , the mention of the shipping price included is not on the 2 other screenshots

Comment: I have set price to 100 , https://nimb.ws/j6AJQl

Comment: If I look at your screenshot, the product displays the price expected. The price that you put in the back office is 100€ . This price is including tax as you set in the settings that all prices put in the backoffice are including tax. So the amount of 98,35€ is wrong. It would display the price excluding tax. The price seems to be wrong though because I suppose your tax is 19%? Can you check your tax settings when you created the tax? Also, which tax class have you applied to this product?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97972/discussion-between-sunny-rahevar-and-sony).

Comment: are you there? I am waiting for you.